# Insert text into anchor tag html

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

I have the following code i would like to insert **bodytext** variable into anchor tag how to achieve this

```js
  function blogBodyRenderer(ctx) {
       var item = ctx.CurrentItem;
       var html = item['Body'];
       var plainBodyText = $(html).text();
       var res = plainBodyText.substring(0, 15);
       alert(res);
       var str2 = 'Read more...';
       var bodytext = res.concat(str2);
       return '<a href="' + ctx.listUrlDir + '/Post.aspx?ID=' + item.ID + '" class="ms-accentText"> + bodytext + </a>';  
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not properly closing the string. Try this

```
'<a href="' + ctx.listUrlDir + '/Post.aspx?ID=' + item.ID + '" class="ms-accentText">' + bodytext + '</a>';
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. sorry i missed it .